# Current rating vs voltage

Tags: homework-and-exercises, electric-current, voltage

If a conductor is rated 16 A at 250V, will the rated current be higher if the conductor is used at 12V?

Miloš

Comment: Hello and welcome to Physics SE! Please note that homework-like questions should **ask about a specific physics concept** and **show some effort** to work through the problem. We want our questions to be useful to the broader community, and to future users. We don't answer homework or worked example type questions.

Comment: Please see [this Meta post on asking homework/exercise questions](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/714/how-do-i-ask-homework-questions-on-physics-stack-exchange) and [this Meta post for "check my work" problems](https://meta.physics.stackexchange.com/questions/6093/should-any-check-my-work-questions-be-made-on-topic) for more guidance on how to edit your question to make it better.

Comment: Do you have a question about what "rated" means, or do you have a question about how to calculate current limits in wires?

Comment: I was actually just trying to see if I can use a connector, rated 16A @250V , for an application with 12VDC with up to 30A. I am aware what "rated" means. The answer below that John provided cleared everything up for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The maximum current is normally limited by heat production in the conductor. If the conductor has a resistance per unit length of $R$ then with a current $I$ the heat produced per unit length is:

$$ P = I^2 R $$

And the limiting value of $I$ is when the heat production raises the temperature enough to damage the conductor or its insulation. Note that the voltage does not appear in this equation. The power depends only on the conductor resistance and the current, so it doesn't matter what the voltage of the power supply is.

Comment: @Milos, just to add to this answer: for a conductor, we're assuming the voltage rating specified is the breakdown voltage of the insulation on the wire, not the voltage across the ends of the wire. That's why its not included in the equation John shows..